# Javascript Tag cloud font size rolling over after 10 occurrances

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON string from my DB that gets fed into the script below, your basic tag cloud with font size being increased based on frequency.  My problem is that once a frequency hits ten (10), the font size goes back to the same as if it were one.  I've had similar problems where I was passing a string in PHP instead of INT, but that is not the case here.

`{"tags":[{"tag":"programming","freq":11}]}`

```
$(function() {

  $.getJSON("tagcloud.php", function(data) {

    $("<ul>").attr("id", "tagList").appendTo("#tagCloud");

    //create tags
    $.each(data.tags, function(i, val) {

      //create item
      var li = $("<li class=\"tagInfo\">");

      //create link
      $("<a>").text(val.tag).attr({class:"a",href:"index.php?page=tagdata&tagName=" + val.tag }).appendTo(li);

      /*If I set the first equation to more than what my frequency is (10000 here for caution), it works fine.  
      But the equation in the line commented out where `(val.freq / 10 < 1) is not
      giving me the correct output.  Am I missing ensuring this variable is an 
      INT in my JS after it's retrieved in JSON? */
      li.children("a").css("fontSize", (val.freq / 10000 < 1) ? val.freq / 10 + 1 + "em": (val.freq / 10 > 2) ? "2em" : val.freq / 10 + "em");                       
      //li.children("a").css("fontSize", (val.freq / 10 < 1) ? val.freq / 10 + 1 + "em": (val.freq / 10 > 2) ? "2em" : val.freq / 10 + "em");                       

      //add to list
      li.appendTo("#tagList");
    });         
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this *(never mind the syntax changes -- it's just for readability)*:

```
li.children("a").css("fontSize", 
    ((val.freq / 20) <= 1 ? (val.freq / 20) + 1 : 
     (val.freq / 10) >= 2 ? 2 : (val.freq / 10)) + "em");
```

**Why...**

Due to the initial use of less than `<` expression, rather than `<=`, your algorithm negates `10 / 10` as true and ends up in the "else" segment of your ternary statement (returning `1em`).

Another issue your going to run into is that you've limited yourself to a very small range of values -- in this case, *font sizes*. Currently, your equation results in the following:

```
 divisor | frequency | product | size (em)
-------------------------------------------
    10        1          0.1       1.1
    10        2          0.2       1.2
    10        3          0.3       1.3
    10        4          0.4       1.4
    10        5          0.5       1.5
    10        6          0.6       1.6
    10        7          0.7       1.7
    10        8          0.8       1.8 
    10        9          0.9       1.9
    10        10         1.0       1.0 
    10        11         0.1       1.1
    10        12         0.2       1.2
    ...       ...        ...       ...
```

You can resolve the issue so that it will scale up, from `1.05em` to `2em` (with increments of `.05em`), by simply changing the divisor from 10, to 20. This will help to make sure that the size keeps scaling until it hits your threshold, `2em`.

I would suggest marking up some of your variables as currently the size scales up for every 1 *hit*, and stops scaling at 20 *hits*. You know, `20 -> 200, 10 -> 100`. Either way...

Comment: Works great! Thanks.  I imagine I'll scale them eventually, but I don't have enough content to make it effective right now.  

I think I may eventually do a trending instead of overall count in the future, so maybe I'll revisit the whole concept then.

Thanks again.